# PhoneGap: admob is undefined

Tags: javascript, cordova, admob, phonegap-plugins

I follow this tutorial : http://www.joshmorony.com/monetizing-your-phonegap-build-app-with-admob/

Here is my code :

**config.xml**

```
<gap:plugin name="com.admob.plugin" version="5.3.0" source="plugins.cordova.io" />
```

**index.js**

```
function onDeviceReady() {

  admob.initAdmob("ca-app-pub-##/##","ca-app-pub-##/##");
  admob.showBanner(admob.BannerSize.BANNER, admob.Position.BOTTOM_APP);
  admob.cacheInterstitial();
}
onDeviceReady();

document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);


function showInterstitial(){
  admob.isInterstitialReady(function(isReady){
    if(isReady){
      admob.showInterstitial();
    }
  });
}
```

**Later in index.js**

```
  showInterstitial();
```

When I lunch my app, i've got **admob is undefinded**

Comment: Just a suggestion, I think the reference in the `config.xml` is out dated. See the docs on Github https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro/wiki/Difference-of-Plugin-IDs#cordova-plugin-admobpro

Comment: I think it should be `<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-admob" source=“npm"/>` or `<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-admobpro" source=“npm"/>` depending on what version you want to use

Comment: Still doesn't work :/ Do I have to do something in terminal ?

Comment: I'm not used to building apps from command line I use the PhoneGap Build service so I'm not sure. I think that plugin got updated quite a bit though so a lot of tutorials are now outdated and don't match the latest release

Answer (score 0):

Use this plugin cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-admobpro

```
    var admobid = {};
        admobid = { // for Android
        banner: 'ca-app-api_id',
        interstitial: 'ca-app-api_id'
    };

AdMob.prepareInterstitial({
    adId: admobid.interstitial,
    autoShow: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The plugin name is incorrect, you should use this one:

```
<gap:plugin name="admob-google" source="plugins.cordova.io" />
```

Also remove version tag to get always the last version of the plugin.